# PHP and JavaScript based support wizard

Tags: php, javascript, html, css

I need to develop a broadband support wizard. It needs to be a step by step troubleshooter, as in different buttons will lead you down a different "path" to troubleshoot with a user.

I was wondering what the most efficient way of doing this would be, as right now all I can think of is a class with a `$steps` property looking like so:

```
private $steps = array(
    'start' => array( // this is the unique identifier for this step
        'text' => 'Is this a router problem or an exchange problem?' // the text for this step
        'buttons' => array( // holds the buttons which lead to the other steps
            array('text' => 'Router problem', 'goto' => 'router-problem'), // goto is the unique identifier for another step
            array('text' => 'Exchange problem', 'goto' => 'exchange-problem')
        )
    )
);
```

And then use `$steps` on the page to make the elements, and use JavaScript to skip down the steps.

This seems incredibly inefficient though, and I was wondering if there was a best practice way of doing what I want. Essentially a tree structure which the user can follow paths down to get to the end of a path, hopefully with it being the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, using a large configuration array will severely hinder your ability to modify the application. If you need to make an update to either the configuration array or the method to process the array, then both of them may need to be changed and will require a ton of testing (if you don't have unit testing setup).

Your best bet is to keep everything very simple. Keep all content within the HTML and your life will be much easier. Not only will this be easier, but the application will run faster as well. If you're okay with reloading/redirecting to a new page for every step, then keep each step defined and within one PHP file. So, the user starts at index.php and goes to a new page step2.php depending on which button they click.

If you need to go to the next step without reloading the page, then AJAX is your best friend. Just load the new content in the main container and continue from there. The same tree structure can be setup, as described below. The only difference is that each button is an AJAX call rather than a redirect. This may be overkill for a simple troubleshooter, but it does look good!

You've stated that you wanted a tree structure. You can setup your own file system directory to help organize your application, and this is highly recommended. This is simple enough to do within PHP files and redirection. For example, if the user is at the start and has a router issue, then you redirect the user to `http://domain.com/router/index.php` using router as a sub directory. If they have a specific router issue, such as a firewall, you can redirect the user to `/router/firewall.php` or `/router/firewall/index.php` depending on how specific your needs will be for the troubleshooter. You can easily conform to one structure ideology and stick with it to simplify the navigation.

Also, databases are pointless and cumbersome for static content. If this was a highly dynamic web application, then it would be very helpful, but anything static wont need much more then HTML with PHP and Javascript.

Last but not least, I suggest putting all common page content into include files. Think of each include as no more than a template for each page. For example, a main navigation menu would be added to a page using a PHP include, so it can be updated on all pages by changing only one file. If you do this, then static pages instead of configuration arrays is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Storing this in a database would be better, more dynamic, and easier to update in the future. You will need several tables that relate to each other (steps table, step_buttons, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Agile UI offers a wizard component, which may be useful in case like that:

http://agile-ui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html

Steps are defined dynamically, so you can implement logic and introduce extra steps based on logic. Everything is written in PHP, no array logic, making it easy to understand and support.